# I am trying to add a text area based on Other being chosen as one of the mulitple selects in a select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a textarea based on the "Other" being one of the choices in an array.

Here is the code.

First the div and the select statement

```
<div id="refertodiv">
   <label for="referto">Refer to:</label>
   <select multiple="multiple" name="referto" id="referto">
     <option value="1">Infection Control</option>
     <option value="2">Medical</option>
     <option value="3">Nursing Administration</option>
     <option value="4">Personnel</option>
     <option value="5">Quality Committee</option>
     <option value="6">Risk and Safety</option>
     <option value="7">Other</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Here is the function.

```
$(function(){
$("#referto").change(function(){
    var rechange = [];
    $('#referto :selected').each(function(){
        rechange[$(this).val()]=$(this).text();
    });
    var textarea = "<textarea name='referother' id='referother' />";
    if($.inarray("Other",rechange)>-1){
        $("#referto").append(textarea);
    } 
})
})
```

Comment: Doesn't it need to be `inArray()` (note the capitalization)?

Comment: You have a typo in the function inarray() is inArray()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use arrays at all. This code will add the textarea if other is selected and remove the textarea if other is deselected.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LimitedWard/3GKm5/1/

```
$("#referto").change(function(){
    var otherSelected = false;
    $('#referto option:selected').each(function(){
       if ($(this).text() == "Other")
       {
           otherSelected = true;
       }
    });
    if (otherSelected) /* add textarea if otherSelected was true */
    {
        var textarea = "<textarea name='referother' id='referother' />";
        $("#referto").after(textarea);
    }
    else /* remove textarea if otherSelected was false */
    {
        $("#referother").remove();
    }
});
```

Note that you were using `.append()` which places the textarea inside the `<select>` element, whereas I used `.after()` which places the textarea just after the `<select>` element. Putting the textarea inside another input is invalid.

Comment: @user1554967 Sorry for the late reply. To use append, you would have to target the parent of the `#referto` element. This is because `append()` places a child element at the end of a parent element whereas `after()` places a sibling element just after another element. Using `$('#referto').append(textarea)` places the textarea inside the select element, which leads to very bad HTML.